# Anyway of enforcing git tag consistency?

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm working on a project in a team of about 6 or 7 people, and we're using git for the CVS.

When we do releases, we tag master at it's current state (after all branch merging is done) and use that tag to deploy.

The tagging scheme we use is [project version].[tag number].[year-month-date][# of tags released today].

For example the project is verison 5.0 of a website, and the tag is done today, so the tag would look like:

`5.0.85.2014020601`

The project's been going on for over a year now so when we do "git tag" we get a huge list of tags which aren't all ordered numerically, so it's tricky figuring out what tag number we should give a release and it often gets messed up.

Is there anyway we can enforce a consistent tagging scheme without needing to write any scripts, or a simple way to generate the tag numbers for us?

Our remote repository is hosted on a gitlab server we have running, and we're all working on Linux environments.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of an easy way to enforce the tag formatting in Git (Without writing a script or a hook that said).

But would the following command help you?

```
  git describe --tags
```

It displays the latest tag (chronological) that can be reached from the branch

Comment: Funny, I tried it but it actually gave me a tag number for three tags before, not the latest.

Comment: I wonder if you have to sync your tags with the remote ones with: git fetch --tags or if it is automatic...

Comment: I tried git fetch and git fetch --tags, and so did my colleague. Both are showing the same tag from 3 versions ago.

Comment: Are the tags from the same branch? (I'm getting dry here...)

Comment: Yes, all tags are made on the master branch. I don't know then, maybe it's just something with our code base then.

Comment: Would you mind take a screenshot of some history visual? Like in gitg / tig or a simple git log that would display tags?